# Why doesn't the H field form closed loops?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

As one learns really early on in electro-magnetism, the field lines of the magnetic flux density **B** form closed loops. However, the magnetic field intensity **H**, related to **B** = $\mu_r\mu_0$ **H**, doesn't always.

How can we understand the difference?

Comment: the source of H are the poles

Comment: I am looking for a bit more insight @hyportnex than "the source of H are the poles", that can be found in every textbook but I would like to understand better why that is the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vector field forms closed loops is it is divergence free. This is the case for the magnetic field $\mathbf{B} $
$$
\nabla \cdot \mathbf{B} =0
$$
From your definition of $\mathbf{H}$, taking $\mu_0$ to be constant over space
$$
\mathbf{H} = \frac {\mathbf{B}} {\mu_0 \mu_r} 
$$
$$
\nabla\cdot\mathbf{H}
= \frac{1} {\mu_0}\left(\frac{1} {\mu_r}\nabla \cdot\mathbf{B} + \mathbf{B}\cdot \nabla\frac{1} {\mu_r} \right) 
\\
= - \frac{\mathbf{B}\cdot\nabla\mu_r} {\mu_0 \mu_r^2} 
$$
as such it is the varying of $\mu_r$ over space that causes the divergence of $\mathbf{H}$ to be nonzero, and its field lines to not be closed.